# Lint Fail for Cocoapods

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, lint

I have an Objective-C Library and I am trying to update the podspec to cocoapods. When I do the "pod spec lint" command I get the following error:

```
[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error.
[!] The validator for Swift projects uses Swift 3.0 by default, if you are using a different version of swift you can use a `.swift-version` file to set the version for your Pod. For example to use Swift 2.3, run: 
    `echo "2.3" > .swift-version`.
```

Here is my podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "OSwitch"
  s.version      = "0.2.0"
  s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
  s.summary      = "OSwitch is a customisable switch control writen in Objective C."
  s.homepage     = 'https://github.com/OyaSaid/OSwitch'
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/OyaSaid/OSwitch.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.platform     = :ios, "7.0"
  s.ios.frameworks = ['UIKit', 'Foundation']
  s.source_files = 'OSwitch/Classes/**/*.{h,m}'
  s.requires_arc = true
end
```

Why does this show when I have an objective C library. And how do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows that because you're able to use both swift and Objc languages in your pod.
Just run the following command in the terminal:

```
    `echo "2.3" > .swift-version`
```

Replace "2.3" with your current Swift version in XCode, if you're on 3.1 for example replace it with "3.1". It will create a swift version file in your pod-project folder. And then you can run the lint command to validate your podspec.

Comment: it's also possible to specify it as arguments like `pod spec lint <file> --swift-version=2.3`

Comment: Hey, I used the command in the terminal but of no use. No swift version file was created. Can you explain or edit your answer with some screenshots please.