# Create ios framework with private source

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I want to create objective-c framework.
I generate podspec,test with "lib lint" push trunk.
Part of my podspec : 
 s.source_files = 'MyFramework/*.{h,m}'

s.public_header_files = 'MyFramework/*.h'

s.private_header_files = 'MyFramework/Private.h'

But after all I saw that all my files is public.

[image]

Help me smbd, how can I hide .m files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lint Fail for Cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634963/lint-fail-for-cocoapods)

Answer (score 0):

Your XCode is probably on swift 3.1. just run in your pod folder:

`echo "3.1" > .swift-version`

Or replace it with another version of swift if you're on 2.3 for example.

It will create .swift-version file so after that you can run `pod lib lint` or `trunk push` command again.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way of a solution. I  make archive my frameworks and add it in the project folder. Later in podspec I wrote s.vendored_frameworks = *archive* (necessary to specify a full way). Also in s.source_files I wrote my headers.

```
 s.source_files = 'MyFramework/Classes/*.{h}'
 s.vendored_frameworks = 'Frameworks/MyFramework.framework'
```

Answer (score -1):

just follow this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcSqF_vnvD0), and when it says to do below command

```
pod trunk push xyz.podspec
```

instead follow this

```
pod trunk push xyz.podspec --allow-warnings
```

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)